# How can I get the particular point clicked on in a THREE.Points object?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to use a raycaster to determine points on a 2d surface of points...

```
function dynamic(x) { x.dynamic = true; return x; }
geometry.addAttribute("position", dynamic(new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3)));
geometry.addAttribute("color", dynamic(new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3)));
var grid = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
scene.add(grid);

function mouseDownHandler(event) {
    if (event.button == 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
        var box = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouse.x = ((event.clientX - box.left) / (box.right - box.left)) * 2.0 - 1.0;
        mouse.y = ((event.clientY - box.bottom) / (box.top - box.bottom)) * 2.0 - 1.0;
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(grid);
        if (intersects.length > 0) {
// Why does my intersect not work?
// I _believe_ I'm calculating the mouse positions correctly.
// But, the intersects are always way off. (Or, I'm misinterpreting
// something...)
            console.log("mouse: ", mouse);
            console.log("First Intersect:", intersects[0]);
            console.log("First Point:", intersects[0].point);
        }
    }
}
```

I have the full code here:
https://som.hex21.com/threejs/wtf/ Is the page, and
https://som.hex21.com/threejs/wtf/js/gridsearch.js is the code..

My issue is in mouseDownHandler. Basically, when you click on the mouse, I want it to tell me which point was clicked. But, when I click say on the bottom left of the grid, mouse is (near) {-1,-1}, which I think is what is expected, right?) and top right is near {1,1}.

How am I supposed to read the index of the point that was clicked? I clicked on all four corner points, and I would expect that at least *one* of them would be 0 just given the way that I constructed the data. (Just 2 nested for loops) But, they never are, and the points in intersects[0].point always seems very far off. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone else reading this. The mouse calculation was fine. The real problem was that

`camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, 1, 1e-16, 1000);`

was too small of a minimum distance for the perspective camera to work with. Once I changed it to

`camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, 1, 1e-2, 1000);`

Everything was fine. In retrospect, it makes sense, odds are some sort of underflow was happening somewhere. (You can see it working here:
    https://som.hex21.com/threejs/ftw/ and failing with that single change  here: https://som.hex21.com/threejs/wtf/ (Both with the original mouseDownHandler))

Answer (score -1):

You mouse coords should be:

```
var box = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var mouseX = event.clientX - box.left;
var mouseY = event.clientY - box.top;

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2 (
        2 * (mouseX / canvas.width) - 1,
    1 - 2 * (mouseY / canvas.height));
```

You can find more info at: http://soledadpenades.com/articles/three-js-tutorials/object-picking/

Comment: Thanks! But, I'm nearly positive that my way and your way are identical.. Nevertheless, I made that change, and it still doesn't get the right spot. Any other ideas? (What's on the site should have the code the way you suggest now...)

Comment: The signs of your `mouse.y` are not the same. Maybe a fiddle is in order.

Comment: I have:

   var box = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
   var mouseX = event.clientX - box.left;
   var mouseY = event.clientY - box.top;

   var mouse = new THREE.Vector2 (
    2 * (mouseX / canvas.width) - 1,
       1 - 2 * (mouseY / canvas.height));

in my code now... (I just cut and pasted.) and, it still doesn't work..?

Ugh. code doesn't get formatted in comments, looks like.